# How to achieve misty look and vintage colors like Jaime Ibarra?

Tags: post-processing, technique, image-processing, reverse-engineering, cross-processing

How are the color tones and the misty look achieved in the photo below?

Does the technique/s have a name?

(Note: link is NSFW.)

Link to image - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-swr6UsPvGjM/Tqz5BCOLR6I/AAAAAAAAgKU/J4KVUTekyrw/s750/Jaime-Ibarra_Raven.jpg

Link to gallery - https://plus.google.com/photos/113464569897311842405/albums/5657062867692530241/5657062866607182066

Comment: Which photo? There is more than 1 photo on the NSFW link on a Google Plus page. This questions feels more link-bait than a serious Photography question!

Comment: There was [an image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-swr6UsPvGjM/Tqz5BCOLR6I/AAAAAAAAgKU/J4KVUTekyrw/s750/Jaime-Ibarra_Raven.jpg) in original question, but it was removed by another user. Most likely the asker is not licensed to publish the image here.

Comment: I did not want to embed the person's image without permission, no link bait here, when I visited that link an image out of the gallery was displayed in a light box effect. The image changed because I would have had to go through all the galleries to find the one I first linked to, this image had a similar effect. No link bait here sorry. I will attempt to amend the link if all the galleries are being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Just playing around in LR on an image of my own, I used a simple cross process technique with a bit of light tone reduction.

I used the "Inside Lightroom COL Cross Processed" preset.

It also looks like there's a white texture added to several of the images.

Answer (score 1):

The “misty” look in the first image is probably due to some internal reflections caused by strong direct light entering the lens.
You could try that, but it could also turn out horrible, especially if you don't use high-end lenses.
Another way to reproduce it would be to lift a bit the brightness of the whole scene in post processing - not the “exposure” slider, the good old brightness control: you do want to lift everything (shadows, midtones, highlight) of the same amount.

Regarding colors, without specific detail on the software you're using, I would suggest to use the curves adjustments.
Adjust separately the RGB channels, giving each one a subtle s-curve or reverse s-curve (to your taste).